# Convert SVN Subdirectory to Git

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

I would like to ditch SVN for Git. My current SVN repository setup has projects under trunk (`/trunk/projecta`, `/trunk/projectb`, etc. with tags and branches at `/tags/projecta-1.0`, etc.). I would like to create distinct Git repos for each of these projects by pulling them out of SVN using git-svn.

I've successfully pulled the entire SVN repo down to a local Git repo but all of the projects exist in the same Git repo now. Is it possible to pull them apart at this point?

Comment: I've heard that there are better-in-the-long-run options for converting Subversion to Git than git-svn (because git-svn is specialized for being able to commit back), but I don't have any references to hand.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is tricky. To get, e.g., the tags for a project, all its tags have to be under a common directory, but your structure has all projects sharing a single tag directory.

Perhaps you could move /tags/projecta-1.0 to /tags/projecta/1.0 and so on, and then import projects into git one at a time:

```
git-svn init --trunk=trunk/projecta --tags=tags/projecta ...
```

I don't know if this will work as expected, so ***please* do this on a copy of your repository, not the original!**

Comment: I wasn't too concerned with the tags/branches, so this worked dandily. I executed this on my Ubuntu Lynx box:

"""git svn clone --no-metadata --trunk=trunk/projecta http://svn/repo projecta"""

Comment: it's quite trick, the easiest way is to create two new git project, and copy ProjectA and ProjectB to git repo correspondently, but this will lose all history:(

Answer (score 5):

I recently had to solve this problem with a reasonably complex case (extracting the utahrle files from BRL-CAD's overall history to make a separate GIT project) and ended up using svn2git with a rules file.  These were my steps - not sure if it's the "right" way but it seems to have succeeded in my case:

1. Make sure svn2git is installed, as well as subversion and git 
   (enable git subversion support if not already present.)  Note
   that there seem to be multiple programs using the project name
   svn2git - the one I used is this one:

   http://www.gitorious.org/svn2git

   This article from KDE got me started:

   http://techbase.kde.org/Projects/MoveToGit/UsingSvn2Git
2. Obtain local copy of your svn repository.  Note that this 
   is not a *checkout* of the repository but a full copy of 
   the entire SVN repo data set.  Sourceforge makes this possible 
   with an rsync option - see their docs for details: http://sourceforge.net/p/forge/documentation/rsync%20Backups/.  I'm not 
   sure about other sites.

   ```
   mkdir svn_repo
   cd svn_repo
   rsync -av svn.code.sf.net::p/PROJECTNAME/MOUNTPOINT .
   cd ..
   ```
3. create identity map between svn committers and git committers

   file: account-map

   ```
   svnname1 Jane Coder <coder@foo.org>
   svnname2 Joe Techwriter <writer@foo.org>
   ```
4. create svn2git filtering rules to capture the utahrle history.
   I'll post the full utahrle example here that shows how to 
   follow the history around between different directories, but 
   I'd expect most cases wouldn't be quite this bad:

   file: rules

   ```
   create repository utahrle
   end repository

   match /brlcad/trunk/libutahrle/
      min revision 1
      max revision 22796
      repository utahrle
      branch master
   end match

   match /brlcad/trunk/tools/
      min revision 1
      max revision 22814
      repository utahrle
      branch master
   end match

   match /brlcad/trunk/src/other/libutahrle/
      min revision 22797
      repository utahrle
      branch master
   end match

   match /brlcad/trunk/src/other/URToolkit/
      min revision 22815
      repository utahrle
      branch master
   end match

   match /
   end match
   ```
5. Run svn-all-fast-export to generate archive (svn_repo is the directory holding 
   your full copy of the subversion files):

   svn-all-fast-export --identity-map account-map --rules rules svn_repo
6. Using the above rules file, utahrle holds the resultant git 
   repository. Use gitk to check that the history we expect to see 
   is actually present, then (if you are using this repo as an online
   source archive) use standard sourceforge procedures 
   for uploading an existing git repository.

Answer (score 1):

When the repository layout is quite complex, there is a tool called `svn2git` which makes it possible to convert a complex repository with a ruleset.

You can download it here: http://gitorious.org/svn2git/
The program needs to be compiled, it needs the Qt, Apache and SVN header files.

Answer (score 1):

Another program for one-time conversion of Subversion repository is [Svn2Git](https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git) (different than vdboor's answer), it has fewer dependencies and did great job for my repositories.