# Push a specific folder to github from a svn repository

Tags: svn, git, github, git-svn

I have a svn repository that I need to push a SDKs' folder to a github repository. The catch is that I need to preserve the svn history related to the SDKs' folder and push it, with their respectives commit messages, to github.

I've created a git repository using git-svn but I'm stuck on what to do next. I've also tried to add a submodule, for the SDKs folder, but for some reason I can't push it back to the svn repository.

Comment: Do you want to replace the svn repo, or use both git and svn in parallel?

Comment: I have to use both git and svn :(

Answer (score 0):

You can [convert a SVN subdirectory to a git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752168/convert-svn-subdirectory-to-git) provided the SVN repo has the right structure (for tags especially)

Once that git repo exists,

- it can be pushed to its own GitHub repo 'GitHub_SDK'
- it can be reference by your original GitHub repo as a submodule

That way, any modification made to that submodule will end up in your independent GitHub_SDK repo (or its local copy) and can be pushed back (`git svn dcommit`) to its SVN repo.

Comment: I've tried that before but for some reason the submodule gets deleted in svn every time I try to commit it.