# Can I use git-svn to create a Git repository from a single directory in a Subversion repository?

Tags: git, git-svn

I will be tracking a new project in a Git repository. The project has a dependency on an older library; the library is stored in a directory in a branch in a Subversion repository. The library’s directory has many sibling directories—other projects—that I’m not interested in. What I’d like to do is to bridge *just this single directory* into a Git repository using git-svn. (I’ll be including this repository as a submodule in the new project’s directory, although I don’t think that’s germane to my question.) Is it possible to bridge just part of a Subversion repository like this?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13447705/is-git-svn-compatible-with-git-subtree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to bridge just part of a Subversion repository like this

It is possible, with **[`svn2git`](https://www.gitorious.org/svn2git)** [**filter rules**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14675843/6309)
(another approach would use [`git-svn` with a non-standard layout](http://java.dzone.com/articles/howto-partially-clone-svn-repo))

It is best if you don't have to push back to the svn repo though.